What is a Price Feed?
I have tried to research about this and have gotten a term which I understand is associated (Oracles) but I so far I have not gotten a plain definition.
I understand their use I.E they are needed for prices of coins to be somewhat the same in different exchanges or regions. But I would like to know more of what it is or at least some descriptive information on them, as so far I only get products (If that is how I should call it) offered by some organizations like ChainLink and Pyth. Any abstract that goes to explain them would be greatly appreciated.

I believe you will find many resources on topic of oracles when you search the web (https://web3elaine.medium.com/understanding-the-oracle-solanas-indispensable-defi-infrastructure-f92e2799054a, https://www.thetie.io/insights/research/blockchain-oracle-comparison/ ...)
